# How to start off in website not index wampserver

Tags: wamp, wampserver

How to make it so when people connect to me website they dont start off in the index but in the website
[Picture of Index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZKVZ.png)

Comment: Make a file called `index.php` or `index.html` and that will automatcially get run by Apache

Comment: How do i make it auto run?

Comment: By calling it `index.php` or `index.html` these are names APache expects to see and when it does it runs them if you dont specifiy any other specific file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make an `index.php` file and put the following inside:

```
<?php
    header('location: ./myfile.html'); //edit the file to redirect to here...
?>
```